# What is the minimum physical distance between two electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, potential-energy

If electrons repel, then it seems to me that energy is required to decrease the distance between two electrons.  Since energy and mass are equivalent, adding energy to a system also adds some mass.  If you confine enough mass/energy in a small enough region, the gravitational force begins to dominate.  As two electrons were brought arbitrarily close together, the amount of energy to halve their remaining distance would increase drastically, furthermore, the space within which that energy must be confined would decrease commensurately.  It seems obvious to me that this could not continue forever.  Eventually the two electrons and the energy needed to bring them into such close proximity would be confined within the corresponding Schwarzschild radius.  Even if electrons are not to be considered as point-particles, wouldn't you eventually bump up against pressure from the Pauli exclusion principle, to the same effect?  I understand that the uncertainty principle could come to bear quite strongly in a case like this, but I'm really looking for an answer rather than being told my question is wrong, so if you have to, consider it a cloud of some greater number of electrons, to cut to the heart of the question, which I guess is:

At what distance would it become impossible to bring N electrons any closer together without producing a gravitational singularity?

I would prefer an answer where N=2, despite the fact that such a scenario may not be meaningful, it will help me visualize the general principle behind it.  For example, one could treat the electrons as point particles, ignore the uncertainty principle, and just plot a graph of the amount of energy needed for a given separation, and then find where that line intersects with the Schwarzschild radius - which I acknowledge would only answer the question - "Despite it not being possible to bring two electrons to a mutual distance of 10^-49 m, if you were to naively project the math involved, that is the point where escape velocity would equal c."

Please forgive my limited understanding, I engage in physics thought experiments recreationally only and have no formal training or background.

Please help me enhance my intuition with a concrete solution to the distance at which 2 electrons would need to be, for the energy required to bring them there to exceed the Schwarzschild radius of that energy.

Comment: It's my (rather limited) understanding that the charge density of an electron is already higher than it should be given the lower limits on its radius and that it should be a black hole (but isn't).  I don't think we know enough about electron structure to be sure what's going on.

Comment: Also, see the treatment here which addresses some of your question: http://cow.physics.wisc.edu/~ogelman/guide/e/

Comment: They have been bounced off of other electrons at distances down to about $10^{-18}\,\mathrm{m}$ (and show no sign of internal structure to that level).